# Why docker stops already running containers during startup?

Tags: docker

I have some containers running with docker server up. Now if the daemon crashes for some reason (I killed it using kill -9 $Pid_of_daemon to reproduce this behavior), and if I start the docker server again, why does it kill the old running container. The behavior I want is it should go ahead even if there are already running containers. The only reason I found out is, when daemon crashes, it looses its stdin, stdout pipes with the container, so it can no more attach to the old running containers. But if my container does not want stdout, stdin or stderr, then why would the daemon is killing it during startup. Please help